# didChangeState matchstarted

Tags: match

help ! all,

When "Match started! Expected Player Count:1"

but can not call  "didChangeState"

my code is :

===============================

```
-(IBAction)play{

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc]init];
    request.minPlayers = min;
    request.maxPlayers = max;

    mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc]initWithMatchRequest:request];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate =self;
    [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

}

- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.myMatch = match; 
    self.myMatch.delegate = self;  

    NSLog(@"Match started! Expected Player Count:%d  %@",match.expectedPlayerCount, match.playerIDs);
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state
{ NSLog(@"OK!"); }
```

====================

it can not give me "OK!"
but i can see "Match started! Expected Player Count:1"

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think the problem was in apple servers.
Because I did nothing and after half an hour past it started to work again.
Without any troubles.